# Most appropriate Character to Pad Strings

Tags: string, character, special-characters, padding, vhdl

What is the most appropriate character to use when padding a string (0 to 127 range preferably)? I want/prefer it to be a non-printing character and doesn't have a [ascii symbol](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/) associated with it.

I tried [`NUL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) but that seems to signify the end of a string (nothing prints after it, hence the name "null terminator"). There seems to be a [`PAD`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes) (128) character but I am unsure of its specific use and I would have to manually add that range of characters to my [font library](https://github.com/MadLittleMods/FP-V-GA-Text). Adding the full (0-255) character range is not the end of world just some extra work.

The [Space (32)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) character would work but it doesn't seem like a best practice when there are so many specialty characters. Possibly a character that doesn't take up any space.

I am doing this in VHDL so the characters available are in the [ISO-8859-1 table](http://kireji.com/reference/iso88591.html). You can also look at the character type(VHDL) in [this document](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/standard.vhdl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using the fixed length type `string(1 to LEN)`, I will suggest either of these characters for padding the string:

- NUL character:

  - Pros: String functions can be made to do operations on the "actual" contents, that is anything before the first NUL character.
  - Cons: ModelSim does not present the string nicely, since it also shows all the NUL characters.
- ' ' (space):

  - Pros: Nice ModelSim presentation.
  - Cons: String operations must check for all spaces in the end.

So based on this, the padding character to use for fixed length strings depends on how the string is used.

An alternative to using fixed length VHDL string type (`string(1 to LEN)`) is to use the type `line`, declared in `package` "textio" as `type line is access string;`.  Line is then a "pointer" to a string, called `access` type in VHDL, and the referenced string can be created with the required length only, so padding can be avoided.  Issues:

- Pros:

  - String length can be determined dynamically, so variable length text can fit, even long tests.
- Cons:

  - Simulators, for example ModelSim, can't present the contents of `access` types like ´line´
  - It may be more complicated to make functions/procedures for string/line manipulation due to VHDL language limitations on use of `access` types.
  - Synthesis of ´access´ type is not supported

Comment: The NUL character in Isim stops printing anything after it so if I am concatenating a message like `"msg" & NUL & "more"` and `report`, I only see "msg". The Space character works it is just that it has no specialty and is a printing character (takes up space in all situations). I am leaning towards adding C128 (128) just because it is non-printing, and is `PAD` in the control codes (see [this page](http://kireji.com/reference/iso88591.html)). The specialty of it makes it easily off limits without hurting any use case.

Comment: This also needs to synthesize and I think the line type is not able to.

Comment: In VHDL the C128 does not have any special meaning, but on the other hand there is no standard method for padding, so if C128 works with the simulator you use, it sounds like a solution.  As you point out, the line type can't be used for synthesis; I will add that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts on this:

1. If you insist on a nonprinting character, you have many to choose from. Consider the BEL | 7 | CTRL-G.  It's non-printing. Rarely used anymore. It can be typed in the terminal and many editors (CTRL-G). If it does "print" accidentally (in a terminal, for example), it's harmless. And fun. All    else equal, BELs are fun. ^G ^G ^G :-)
2. Use a *printing* character that you don't otherwise use. This will    make debugging and string constants much easier. It does require    making an otherwise printing character off limits to your application. e.g. backslash, backtick, tilde, etc.

I lean toward option 2.  You'll see your pad characters at a glance, you'll be able to type them.  You won't need a special font or editor if source or data moves between systems.

Comment: You can easily type special characters in VHDL including non-printing ones by concatenating "NUL", "BEL", "STX", etc with a normal string (see [this page for more](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/standard.vhdl)). I do not like BEL because its specialty was to ring a bell and it currently holds a dot symbol(from ascii, see [this table for ascii symbols](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/)) in my font library. I am looking for something that preferably I will not be able to see in most situations but still adhere to fixed length strings in VHDL.